# Why does start() throw an Exception?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Why does the following code declare, that an Exception can be thrown?
Though this is how the method should look according to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html), removing the "throws Exception" part won't lead to a compile error. The documentation doesn't mention why it is necessary.

```
public class GUI extends Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception so it can be caught.  This way if an error occurs your entire app doesnt explode

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks: Yeah but normally you have code like a Stream that can throw an Exception and you NEED to either "throw" or using a "try / catch" to handle that. Here, I can simply remove it without any problems, how's that possible?

Comment: @TrudleR In that example, you have to *either* have a `try`-`catch`, *or* have the method you are in declare it may throw an exception.

Comment: And in this example, you can remove it because the code you have written cannot throw any checked exception. It's legal to have it there, because it's completely possible (from the compiler's perspective) that your code could throw an unchecked exception (`NullPointerException`, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary in the example code you posted. As you observed, the abstract method declared in the `Application` class declares that it may throw an Exception. This means

1. it's legal to implement that method and declare that the overridden method may throw an exception
2. anyone calling `Application.start(...)` must be prepared to catch the exception

The second point becomes important, because the method is called by the JavaFX framework, typically at startup or via a call to `launch(...)`. So you are guaranteed that the JavaFX framework must handle any exception that is throw from your implementation of the `start(...)` method.

In the code you posted, nothing there can throw an exception, so you can readily remove the `throws` clause. However, it becomes useful if, for example, you use FXML:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    // FXMLLoader.load(...) throws an IOException, no need to handle it here
    // we just let it propagate up and the JavaFX framework will handle it
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(...);

    // ...
}
```

This would not compile if you didn't have `throws Exception` in the `start` method (or at least `throws IOException`); in turn that wouldn't compile if the abstract method in `Application` didn't declare it may throw an Exception.